# How to convert a date string for the Calendar control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using the Calendar control, but I've a problem. In particular I stay iterating through a database for get all dates available into a table; like this:

```
public void setFixturesControl()
{
        m_dbConnection.Open();
        string query = "select * from dates";
        SQLiteCommand input = new SQLiteCommand(query, Database.m_dbConnection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader = input.ExecuteReader();
        ...
```

I want add multiple dates in the control, but in this line:

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{

   MainWindow.AppWindow.Calendar.SelectedDates.Add(new DateTime(reader["data"].ToString()));
 }
```

I get this error:

> Can't convert from string to long

What I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the date look like coming out of the database, format wise.

Comment: Looks like your casting it to a string **new DateTime(reader["data"].ToString()** take the **tostring** method out

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot, this is the date format: 2015-08-14 20:30:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `reader["data"]` is already of type `DateTime`, then you just need to remove the `ToString()` call.

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{    
   MainWindow.AppWindow.Calendar.SelectedDates.Add((DateTime)reader["data"]);
}
```

If `reader["data"]` is not a DateTime, then you have to convert it. `DateTime` doesn't have a consutrctor that takes a String. You need to Parse it, instead:

```
while (reader.Read()) 
{    
   MainWindow.AppWindow.Calendar.SelectedDates.Add(DateTime.Parse(reader["data"].ToString()));
}
```